# How to print columns one after the other in bash?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, multiple-columns, cut

Is there any better methods to print two or more columns into one column, for example

input.file

```
AAA    111
BBB    222
CCC    333
```

output:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
111
222
333
```

I can only think of:

```
cut -f1 input.file >output.file;cut -f2 input.file >>output.file
```

But it's not good if there are many columns, or when I want to pipe the output to other commands like `sort`.

Any other suggestions? Thank you very much!

Comment: what is the problem in creating a [mcve]?

Comment: are there always the same amount of columns in all rows?

Comment: Do you actually want the first colunm data firs then second column data and so on ? or is that just casual in the example of the desigred output ? what if you have mixed amounts of rows in the input file ?

Comment: @fedorqui: yes, same here

Comment: @louigi600: for my case, i dont care the order, i actually want to do sort and uniq after that

Comment: @once, if you had made this: ` i dont care the order, i actually want to do sort and uniq after that ` clear while asking the question, you might have got simpler solution

Comment: for ex: `sed 's/\s\+/\n/g' input.file`

Comment: @sp asic: you are right, i havnt thought about the order, i thought there should be a very simple way to print the whole second column down there, so i ask the question this way. However, i think i should keep the question this way since the answer to more difficult question is more valuable

Comment: @once ... no nide to do bothe sort -u eliminates non unique values

Comment: @louigui600: i know sort -u, but i once noticed sort -u and sort|uniq create different output and stop using sort -u. However, i hv no evidence now..

Comment: sort -u also sorts alphabetically (if not otherwise specified) while uniq only suppresses matching adjacent lines (or at least the man page says so).
So for uniq to work correctly (according to the man page) one should first have sorted anyway ... I allays use sort -u ... what the hell if it's really important that you make no mistakes I'll put my data in a table and do a select distinct on the column I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `awk`

```
awk '{if(maxc<NF)maxc=NF;
      for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){(a[i]!=""?a[i]=a[i]RS$i:a[i]=$i)}
      }
     END{
      for(i=1;i<=maxc;i++)print a[i]
     }' input.file
```

Comment: it works!tks! what does (a!=""?a=a"\n"$2:a=$2) mean??

Comment: switch \n to ( \t or \n) ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a GNU awk [array of arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays-of-Arrays.html) to store all the data and print it later on.

If the number of columns is constant, this works for any amount of columns:

```
gawk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)            # loop over columns
           data[i][NR]=$i               # store in data[column][line]
      }
      END {for (i=1;i<=NR;i++)          # loop over lines
                for (j=1;j<=NF;j++)     # loop over columns
                     print data[i][j]   # print the given field
      }' file
```

Note `NR` stands for number of records (that is, number of lines here) and `NF` stands for number of fields (that is, the number of fields in a given line).

If the number of columns changes over rows, then we should use yet another array, in this case to store the number of columns for each row. But in the question  I don't see a request for this, so I am leaving it for now.

See a sample with three columns:

```
$ cat a
AAA    111  123
BBB    222  234
CCC    333  345
$ gawk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) data[i][NR]=$i} END {for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) for (j=1;j<=NF;j++) print data[i][j]}' a
AAA
BBB
CCC
111
222
333
123
234
345
```

---

If the number of columns is not constant, using an array to store the number of columns for each row helps to keep track of it:

```
$ cat sc.wk 
{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
       data[i][NR]=$i
 columns[NR]=NF
}
END {for (i=1;i<=NR;i++)
            for (j=1;j<=NF;j++)
                 print (i<=columns[j] ? data[i][j] : "-")
}
$ cat a
AAA    111  123
BBB    222
CCC    333  345
$ awk -f sc.wk a
AAA
BBB
CCC
111
222
333
123
-
345
```

Comment: Hey, any reason for the downvote? Is there anything that I missed?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that, since all of the indices are numbers, the portable `data[i,j]` could be used just as easily as `data[i][j]`.

Comment: @kdhp good point. Yes, this is GNU awk specific since I am using array of arrays.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{print $1;list[i++]=$2}END{for(j=0;j<i;j++){print list[j];}}' input.file
```

**Output**

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
111
222
333
```

More simple solution would be

```
 awk -v RS="[[:blank:]\t\n]+" '1' input.file
```

Answer (score 2):

Expects tab as delimiter:

```
$ cat <(cut -f 1 asd) <(cut -f 2 asd)
AAA
BBB
CCC
111
222
333
```

Comment: Well, it's customary to comment when downvoting.

Comment: The second solution proposed by James Brown is better and does not beak with mixed column count on the input.

Comment: True that. This is here only to show a better way to construct OP's original idea,

Comment: I equally upvoted the other so net total is neutral ... just wanted the other solution to get better credit.

Answer (score 1):

Since the order is of no importance:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {RS="[ \t\n]+"} 1' file
AAA
111
BBB
222
CCC
333
```

Comment: Hmm, read the question . Where in it  is mentioned that  order is of no importance?

Comment: @mona_sax: In comment # 5, _for my case, i dont care the order_

Comment: Well, it's customary to comment when downvoting.

Comment: pardon me, Iven't  seen that comment.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly, but it works-

```
for i in {1..2} ; do awk -v p="$i" '{print $p}' input.file ; done
```

Change the `{1..2}` to `{1..n}` where `'n'` is the number of columns in the input file

Explanation-

We're defining a variable p which itself is the variable i. i varies from 1 to n and at each step we print the 'i'th column of the file.

Comment: that needs mending according to how many columns you want to terat ... have a look at my proposed solution

Comment: Why am I being downvoted? My solution is the only one that gives the correct output so far.

Comment: I did not downvote! But I guess people were looking for more efficient ways with `awk` by itself, like the two +ve score answers!

Comment: I downvoted because the OP did specify that the input was to have "two or more columns"  while this proposed solution needs mending to work with varying amount of columns.

Comment: @louigi600, I mentioned clearly in my answer that to have multiple columns, you just need to change 2 to 'n'. Did you not read the answer before downvoting?

Comment: yes but that sitl fails if the input would have varying amount of columns ... and it is not clear if the OP wants that ... besides it's not nice to haveto mend your code according to the input you want to use it on. Sorry I don't mean to be rude but I think your answer is missing the point.

Comment: I'm willing to concede that you don't like to change the value of 'n' each time. But I'm afraid you're wrong, this code will not fail for 'varying amount of columns'. But it's alright, let it go.

Comment: @Varun M yes I did ... I still think you miss the point because there are other ways that need not explicitly input anywhere the number of columns, and besides ... as I said before your solution is going to misbehave with mixed number of columns. Did you really read teh OP's question before commenting my solution ?

Answer (score 0):

This will work for an arbitrary number fo space separated colums

```
awk  '{for (A=1;A<=NF;A++) printf("%s\n",$A);}' input.file | sort -u > output.file
```

If space is not the separateor ... let's suppose ":" is the separator

```
awk -F: '{for (A=1;A<=NF;A++) printf("%s\n",$A);}' input.file | sort -u > output.file
```